# Help with the correct parameters to Math.tan

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class a {

    /**
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter #");
        long a = in.nextLong();

        long b = (long) Math.toRadians(a);
        long c = (long) Math.tan(b);

        System.out.println(c);

    }
}
```

Above is my attempt to make Math.tan spit out the correct values of an angle in degrees. I know the method math.tan accepts only angles in radians as a parameter. I can't get correct value for angles of 90, 270... Using a double doesn't yield correct answers.

Comment: can you plz format your code?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use doubles for b and c.

However, note that tan of 90 and 270 degrees is undefined, for example see the graph here:

http://www.intmath.com/Trigonometric-graphs/4_Graphs-tangent-cotangent-secant-cosecant.php

Answer (score 3):

Of course you cannot get a nice value for 90 degrees, because `tan` is not defined for that angle. This is clear from the definition

```
tan(x) = sin(x) / cos(x).
```

If x = 90°, then cos(x) = 0, so you get a division by zero. The same thing applies to 270°, and in fact all odd multiples of 90°. (Now, computers are numerical beasts, and pi/2 radians cannot be represented exactly (in any base), in addition to `cos` being computed numerically, so instead of NaN or INF you will likely get a huge number, because the denominator is very close to zero, but not necessarily equal to zero, because of numerical approximation.)

Also, `long` is an integer type. Integer precision might be good enought for your needs when it comes to angles expressed in degrees (0, 1, 2, ..., 358, 359). But in radians, one full lap around a circle corresponds to the angles 0 radians to 2π, where 2π ~ 6.28. Hence `b` cannot be an integer, and neither can `c`.

Comment: hmm i put his code into intellij, changed everything to double, and entering 90 doesn't return NaN.  I also tried tan of Math.PI/2.

Comment: @andreas, it returns 1.633123935319537E16

Comment: It returns nothing useful, since there is no good reason for it too.  It might be technically best to return Double.NaN since any real number is nonsense.  Doing this might be impractical for a variety of reasons so the results of Math.tan(x) as the asymptotes may simply be artifacts of the approximation algorithm chosen.

Comment: Your answer still mentions division by zero, which doesn't actually happen.  Please remove and I will remove my downvote.

Comment: Mathematically, tan(90°) is undefined because sin(x) / cos(x) would be a division by zero in the case x = 90°. Now numerical algorithms can do sort of whatever they want -- it is not surprising that you get 1.633123935319537E16 which is very large, because the denominator is very close to zero.

Comment: The closer the angle gets to PI/2 (90 degrees), the closer the tan gets to infinity. But PI/2 cannot be exactly represented (it's an irrational number), so you get the value for the closest representable number to PI/2, which lead to a pretty big tangent, but not infinity.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine:

```
public class TanDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int degrees = -89; degrees < 90; ++degrees)
        {
            double radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
            System.out.println("deg: " + degrees + " rad: " + radians + " tan: " + Math.tan(radians));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `double` as a starting point for the input and output of methods like Math.toRadians(double)=>double and Math.tan(double)=>double:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class a {

    /**
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter #");
        double a = in.nextDouble();

        double b = Math.toRadians(a);
        double c = Math.tan(b);

        System.out.println(c);

    }
}
```

On a domain note – as Saxon Druce pointed out – the tangent of `n*90°` (`n*π/2 rads`) is undefined.  Correct answers at exactly `n*π/2` for `n` is an **odd whole number** are not possible.  More specifically `tan(x)` approaches `∞` as `x` increases towards `n*π/2`. It is also true that `tan(X)` approaches `-∞` as `x` decreases towards `n*π/2`.

Comment: º is U+00BA, MASCULINE ORDINAL INDICATOR. My guess is that you are looking for °, U+00B0, DEGREE SIGN

Comment: -1. The tangent of n * 90 degrees is only undefined if n is odd.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: Good eye.  I have corrected the domain of n and the masculine ordinal indicator.  Quid pro quo, correct the division by zero ;)

Comment: OK, I have added a section about the numerical nature of computers. It just was so obvious to me that I didn't consider it worth writing, but given that questions like "OMG! Why isn't 1.0+2.0=3.0 true?!" are that common at SO, it might be worth it after all.